# Configure SQL Server 2000 to use more than 2Gb of memory on a 64bit server

Tags: memory, sql-server-2000, 64-bit

Is there any way to configure SQL Server 2000 Standard Edition (32 bit) to use more than 2Gb of memory on a server running Windows 2003 (64 bit)?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32 bit versions of SQL Server with Advanced Windowing Extensions (AWE) disabled can only access 2 GB of memory, (or 3 GB if the /3gb switch is used in boot.ini - although I'm not sure off the top of my head if this will work on 64 bit Windows).  This is regardless of whether they are running on Windows 2003 32 bit or 64 bit.

Additionally, SQL Server 2000 Standard Edition cannot turn AWE on (it's an Enterprise-only feature), so you're restricted to the 2 GB limit.

Your best bet is to see about upgrading to SQL Server 2005 Standard (32 or 64 bit - 32 bit Standard can use AWE), or the much pricier SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Edition.  As SQL Server 2000 has reached End of Life, my suggestion would be to go the 2005 Standard route.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this Microsoft article is of relevance:

[How to configure SQL Server to use more than 2 GB of physical memory](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274750)